# Add C# language support to existing install of VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When I installed VS2008, I unchecked the C# language support, because I did not expect to need it.

Now I need to open a C# project, however, so what can I do to add C# language support?

Comment: Do you have the installation CDs available? Without them, that sounds more or less impossible.

Comment: You do *reinstall* (uninstall and install).

Comment: @PMF I likely have it, I have 3-4 bags of DVDs from the MSDN subscription, and it's somewhere in there, among every possible version or SP of VS2008. I hope the DVD keys are written down on the DVDs themselves, because I'm not sure where I keep them.

Comment: Visual studio installations do not require a key IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should uninstall and install again.